# Upgrade live Universal App to iPad only

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, app-store, universal-binary

We have a live universal app in the AppStore. Our client changed his mind and doesn't want the app to be universal anymore, he wants it to be iPad only.

Since the app was submitted some time ago, there are users who use the iPhone version.

What happens if we submit an upgrade that is iPad only?

Will the review team reject it?

And if it goes live, will the iPhone users receive a notification about the update? If yes in what form?

Or will the iPhone users just be unable to reinstall the app?

Thank you!

Comment: I can tell you what will happen. You will receive a bazillion 1 star ratings from the iphone users. Which will make even more soon-to-be-customers go somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the answer of your question: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/5.0.0.9.1.9.1.1.1.1

See the answer of this question:

"Why are correct device requirements important? Can I update them on iTunes Connect?"

Here is the important part:

"To change your app's device requirement after your first binary submission, submit an app update binary with the new information in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key. You are only allowed to expand your device requirements. **Submitting an update to restrict your device requirements is not permitted**"

This means that if you've already submitted an universal build and then you try to submit only iPhone or only iPad build as update of the universal app ... **Sorry, you can't**.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,  if you try to submit an application that supports fewer platforms than a previous version of the same app, it will be rejected during the upload process.

e.g. 
if version 1 supports ipad and iphone

version 2 cant support just ipad or iphone

Comment: Awesome feature. Do you have any quotable references?

Comment: I've encountered this as well.

Comment: Would love to be able to point a reference for this to clients

Answer (score 0):

iPad users must purchase the app again and cannot update the current version anymore.

People already using the universal app on their iPad will not receive an update. People on the iPhone will receive an update.

---

This is very tricky. It's better to do it not.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has been reported to reject updates that have narrowed hardware requirements compared with the current version in the App store.

If this happens, your clients only option may be to remove the current app from sale and submit a new different iPad-only app.

Answer (score 0):

You can't upgrade live universal app to iPad only.

Apple says the following:

"All device requirement changes must be made when you submit an update to your binary. You are permitted to increase the number of devices your app runs on, but you cannot remove devices you have previously permitted. Removing them will prevent users who have previously downloaded your app from updating it."

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW1) (see "iOS Note")

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same scenario.

You can upgrade application scope (iPhone only to Universal) but you can't degrade application scope (Universal to iPhone only or iPad only).