# Upgrade My free app form Universal to iPhone only

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, ios-universal-app

I release my `free app` to appStore and it's version 1.0 , it is an `Universal app`.

Now I want to release version 1.1 to appStore , and I upgrade it to `iPhone only`.

Does appStore will reject me ?

I have read the [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156382/upgrade-live-universal-app-to-ipad-only) , but it is 2011 , I want to know in 2014 , it will be also reject?

Comment: Yes, your downgrade will be auto-rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't upgrade your app from universal to iphone/ipad only. During Validation time you will get a error.
[image]

Also you can see this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1623/_index.html

Comment: Do you have reject experience because of upgrading your app from universal to iphone? Or any documents?